# Multiple request body parameters, one of which is a Stream. When the Stream is a parameter, there can be no other parameters in the body

Tags: c#, ajax, web-services, wcf, rest

I am trying to upload 3 separate image file with WCF service using Ajax call

working  fine for single image upload

```
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest, UriTemplate = "Saveshot?accesstoken={accesstoken}&notificationid={notificationid}&userid={userid}&dtype={dtype}", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    StatusVO Saveshot(Stream data1, string accesstoken, string notificationid, string userid, string dtype);
```

But not working for 3 image upload its throwing error as

> Operation 'Saveshot' in contract 'IService' has multiple request body parameters, one of which is a Stream. When the Stream is a parameter, there can be no other parameters in the body

```
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest, UriTemplate = "Savshot?accesstoken={accesstoken}&notificationid={notificationid}&userid={userid}&dtype={dtype}", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    StatusVO Saveshot(Stream data1, Stream data2, Stream data3, string accesstoken, string notificationid, string userid, string dtype);
```

Ajax Call

```
function upload() {
        var fd1 = new FormData();
        fd1.append('image', document.getElementById('first').files[0]);
        var fd2 = new FormData();
        fd2.append('image', document.getElementById('sec').files[0]);;
        var fd3 = new FormData();
        fd3.append('image', document.getElementById('third').files[0]);;
        var url = "http://localhost:1187/Iservice.svc/Saveshot?accesstoken=63868f4cf62ae736818da31f32be8c6c&notificationid=5&userid=1&dtype=and";
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            data: JSON.stringify({
                'data1': fd1, 'data2': fd2, 'data3': fd3
            }),
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            type: 'POST',
            success: function (chat) {
                alert(chat.status);
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert('failed');

            }
        });
}
```

How can I achieve it ? 
or else Is there any other way to achieve it ?

Thanks in advance for your responses!

Comment: Do you solve that?

Comment: I think you need send 3 requests to upload each stream separetely